# How to write a label.text in List<>?

Tags: c#

I had this Code:

```
Users user = (from x in myEnt.Users 
              where (x.ID == id) && (x.Title == title) 
              select x).FirstOrDefault();

lblTitle.Text = user.Title;
```

and it worked perfectly. But then I changed it to:

```
List<Users> users= (from x in myEnt.Users 
                    where (x.ID == id) && (x.Title == title) 
                    select x).ToList();

lblTitle.Text = users.Title // not working
```

I get this error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List<> does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple values and one text box, you might need to have them comma separated:

```
lblTitle.Text = String.Join(", ", users.Select(x=> x.Title));
```

The errors states that `users` is a `List` and it doesn't have a property called `Title`. This is self descriptive, each element inside that list has a property called `Title`. That's why we select that `Title` out of each element and sparate them with a comma, build a string out of that and assign that string to the `Text` property of that `Label` control.

Comment: Ist a LoadDetail function. So if you select a gridview and click on it it loads all the Details. And it should only Show the the Information of the selected row. So the Label only have contains one value. And it already worked with FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @JanaPasch So why did you change it to list if you need one value ?

Comment: Sry, yes I need more values, my fault.... But unfortunately get 3 Errors: 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'

2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.StringSplitOptions' 

3: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(string[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @JanaPasch It is `String.Join` and not `.Split`

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! It worked :)